# next payment date save as datetime rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to setup a way to create a daily schedule which compares these columns:

I'm storing paypal IPN `next_payment_date` which comes in different format than the default rails format

**example**

paypal ipn
`"next_payment_date"=>"03:00:00 Oct 06, 2015 PDT"`

rails
`created_at: "2015-10-05 14:24:17"`

These are different formats and I'm not very sure if rails can compare them.

for example

I tried storing the `next_payment_date` as a `datetime` like this

```
subscription = Subscription.find_by(paypal_recurring_profile_token: params[:recurring_payment_id])
if params[:next_payment_date]
  subscription.update_attributes(paid_until: params[:next_payment_date])
end
```

this is the paypal date:

`"next_payment_date"=>"03:00:00 Oct 06, 2015 PDT"`

and this is what rails stores

`paid_until: "2015-10-05 03:00:06"`

it seems like rails does know a bit but it doesn't convert the month and day, just the time.

What is the right way to store these parameters?

**edit**

schema:

```
create_table "payment_notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "params"
  t.integer  "user_role_id"
  t.string   "status"
  t.string   "transaction_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "txn_type"
  t.string   "recurring_payment_profile_id"
end

create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_role_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "paypal_customer_token"
  t.string   "paypal_recurring_profile_token"
  t.datetime "created_at",                                     null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                                     null: false
  t.datetime "paid_until"
  t.boolean  "canceled",                       default: false
end
```

**edit 2**

Trying to convert the string time but it seems out of order:

```
irb(main):006:0> PaymentNotification.last.params[:next_payment_date]
  PaymentNotification Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "payment_notifications".* FROM "payment_notifications"  ORDER BY "payment_notifications"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> "03:00:00 Oct 07, 2015 PDT"
irb(main):007:0> PaymentNotification.last.params[:next_payment_date].to_time
  PaymentNotification Load (4.7ms)  SELECT  "payment_notifications".* FROM "payment_notifications"  ORDER BY "payment_notifications"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> 2015-10-06 03:00:07 +0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ruby/rails classes that deal with dates and times.  Check the class on the different objects you are working with.  Example (in the rails console):

```
2.2.2 :011 > Date.current.class
 => Date
2.2.2 :012 > Time.now.class
 => Time
2.2.2 :013 > DateTime.now.class
 => DateTime
2.2.2 :014 > Time.zone.now.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Decent reference on dealing with these classes: http://stevenyue.com/2013/03/23/date-time-datetime-in-ruby-and-rails/

Answer (score 1):

Created_at is `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` class.

I'm guessing next_payment_date is either `Date` or `DateTime` class- but again- run .class to figure this out.

What's confusing you is that you don't know why rails display them differently- well it's because there are not the same Objects- each of them is a different class.

So:
1) check which class they are

2) Decide which class to convert it do.

3) Compare them.

Example: (assuming the paid_until is in UTC)

```
> next_payment_date_timezone_pdt = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Pacific Time (US & Canada)"].parse("03:00:00 Oct 06, 2015 PDT")
=> Tue, 06 Oct 2015 03:00:06 PDT -07:00
> next_payment_date_timezone_utc = next_payment_date_timezone.in_time_zone('UTC')
=> Tue, 06 Oct 2015 10:00:06 UTC +00:00

> paid_until_timezone_utc = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['UTC'].parse('2015-10-05 03:00:06')
=> Mon, 05 Oct 2015 03:00:06 UTC +00:00
```

Now you can compare them both.
This is the main idea- You should adjust it to your needs.

Comment: when I do `PaymentNotification.find(5).params[:next_payment_date].class` it returns as a string, what would I have to do in this case?

Comment: Can  you please add schema file to question?

Comment: I added the schema to the question

Comment: Hi, I've added more info of what I tried to do at the end of the question, I need a way to format the time in order to compare the `next_payment_date` and the `Time.current` or `Time.now` (not sure which one suits better).